# Setting two equations equal to each other

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to decipher the steps needed to determine the intersection point between curves represented by the two following equations:

$$y= 2\;x+2$$

$$y= \dfrac{128}{(x+1)^2}$$

I know that they intersect at the point (3,8), but I am unsure of whether I should get rid of the denominator first when starting the process. Could someone please work out the project so I can understand how to arrive at this point?

Comment: These are not equations, they are expressions. You are looking for the value of the unknown such that the two expressions are equal. And equations don't have "intersections". Curves do. [Comment posted before the edit.]

Answer (score 2):

One cannot "remove" the denominator of an expression. You want to equate the two expressions and then solve for $x$. So, start with $2x + 2 = \frac{128}{(x+1)^2}$.

Comment: I think the O.P. meant multiplying both sides to remove the denominator as denominator.

Comment: so would the next step be subtracting 2x+2 from both sides?

Comment: I think the next step is to multiply both sides by $(x+1)^2$.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. I think I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Equating the expressions,

$2x+2={128 \over (x+1)^2}\\or, 2(x+1)={128 \over (x+1)^2}\\or, 2(x+1)^3=128\\or,(x+1)^3=64\\or, (x+1)^3-64=0\\or, (x+1)^3-4^3=0\\or,(x+1-4)((x+1)^2+4(x+1)+16)=0\\or,(x-3)(x^2+6x+21)=0\\\text {Either} \space (x-3)=0 \space\text {or} \space x^2+6x+21=0.\\x-3=0 \space \text {gives} \space x=3 $

The quadratic part gives complex roots which are ignored if you are looking for only real solutions.

Then using $y=2x+2 \text {we get} y=2\times3+2=8$

So the point of intersection is $(3,8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(x+1)$ is common factor . So, set it equal to  u.

$$ y= 2 u = 128/u^2 \rightarrow( 2 u^3 = 128) \rightarrow ( u= 4 ) \rightarrow (x=3, y= 8) $$

Comment: Assuming the OP is familiar with $u$ substitution, this seems to be the nicest way to do. (And if the OP is not familiar with $u$ substitution, then they should get familiar with it!)